# How to emphasise the amount or number?

Tags: word-request, emphasis

When I want to say that a price is low, I can say:

> It costs **only** $200.

How can I say that $200 is a lot?

> It costs **< my word >** $200.

Of course, I could say that it costs an arm and a leg, but I'm looking for something that can refer to many nouns, not only prices and is an antonym of *only*.

Is there such word? If there isn't, how can I generally express its meaning?

Comment: Restructure the sentence; “$” goes before the value. (I'd say “It's quite expensive at $200.”)

Comment: There's a slight nuance of additional meaning in, say, *It costs **as much as / anything up to / at least / no less than** $200*, but any of those would also imply that the speaker thinks the price is "relatively high". Alternatively, you could stress the currency unit *It costs two hundred **dollars**!* to make your attitude clear.

Comment: @user2684291, done. Your suggestion refers only to prices. And what about something more general? The price is only an example. I'm looking for a word or an expression that would also fit for an age, an exam score, a year, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to *patternize* English. However, “high” may be suitable to describe some of the above-mentioned.

Comment: @user2684291, patternize? I'm want to be able to express my thoughts precisely.

Comment: You can use "as much as" or "whopping" or "rip-off" depending on context. I believe you read my answer and I decided to delete my answer because of some nonconstructive  comments. Good luck.

Comment: *As much as* works, but *whopping* and *rip-off* are ungrammatical in the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I think the nearest antonym, in that context, is *fully*:

> It costs **fully** $200.

But *fully* is relatively rare, especially in speech; if you went around saying *fully <amount>* anywhere near as often as people say *only <amount>*, it would be a noticeable quirk. Also, *fully* is a bit more restrictive; for example, whereas you can say "only about $200" if it's actually $205, you can't say *"fully about $200" if it's actually only $195. (But in that case you can say "almost $200", which conveys the same idea — *almost* implies that it's high — and is much more common anyway. And, incidentally, if the price is *over* $200, then the usual expression is "over $200", which, again, conveys that it's high. It's only if it's *exactly* $200 that we need something like *fully* to express our reaction.)

There are a few other similar expressions, such as "a whopping $200" or "a full $200", but none of them are all that common. Instead, I think it's more common to convey your feelings on a price with tone of voice and general-purpose "wow" expressions:

> It costs $200!
>   It costs $200??!!!
>   It costs 200 <expletive> dollars!

optionally augmented with other aspects of the wording:

> It costs more than my smartphone!
>   It costs $200. Not worth it.
>   That little piece of plastic costs $200.
>   It costs $200 . . . let's shop around.
>   It costs $200, because they know they have a monopoly.
>   It costs $200, 'cause, not like I *really* needed to make rent this month, anyway . . .

(Not that tone of voice is always successful. I can recall quite a few times where one person expressed surprise about a number, and another person had to ask, "Were you expecting higher, or lower?". Of course, one nice thing about conversation is that we can clarify these things interactively, but it does kinda ruin the moment. :-P )